# Variations between Ashkenazi customs to wrap tefillin in the fingers

Tags: tefilin, ashkenazi, minhagim

When tying tefillin on the fingers, there are two customs among Ashkenazim when saying “verastich li betsedek uvemishpat uvechesed uverachamim”: tying on two fingers (middle and ring) and tying only on the middle finger. Which is the Western Ashkenazi custom and which is the Eastern Ashkenazi custom?

Comment: I can't speak to all Western Ashkenazi communities, but in Frankfurt, the custom was not to recite the possuk of "Veerastich-Li" during hanochas tefillin. Further, different families had different ways of wrapping around the hand, as no one way is me'akev